# How to determine on each chexbox if all the checkboxes in current container and checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

I have a HTML structure where i have multiple section with the same input class and container.

```
<div class="card-columns">
<div class="card" id="role-card-single" data-total-items="6">
   <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Staff Users </h5>
          <div id="selectall">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" value="1">
                  <label>Select all</label>
           </div>

           <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
               <input type="checkbox" name="abc"  class="single-role-input custom-control-input " value="">
                   <label class="custom-control-label" for="30">  Add </label>
           </div>

           <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
               <input type="checkbox" name="def"  class="single-role-input custom-control-input " value="">
                   <label class="custom-control-label" for="30">  Edit </label>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="card" id="role-card-single" data-total-items="6">
   <div class="card-body">
       <h5 class="card-title">Staff Users </h5>
          <div id="selectall">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkall" value="1">
                  <label>Select all</label>
           </div>

           <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
               <input type="checkbox" name="abc"  class="single-role-input custom-control-input " value="">
                   <label class="custom-control-label" for="30">  Add </label>
           </div>

           <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
               <input type="checkbox" name="def"  class="single-role-input custom-control-input " value="">
                   <label class="custom-control-label" for="30">  Edit </label>
            </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is when i check "Select all" it will select all the following Check boxes.

same when i check each checkbox and check all boxes in single container it will also make the "Select All" checkbox of that container.

First thing I have already achieved by following code.

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkall', function() {
    var applyallchecks = $(this).parents('#role-card-single').find('.single-role-input');
    if (this.checked) {
        applyallchecks.prop('checked',true);
    } else {
        applyallchecks.prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Second Part where on check of each single input when all the checkboxes are checked i am trying in this way, but it is not working,

```
$(document).on('change', '.single-role-input' , function(e) {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $parent = $(this).parents('#role-card-single').find('.checkall');
        var applyallchecks = $(this).parents('#role-card-single').find('.custom-checkbox');
        if (applyallchecks.children('.single-role-input') + ":checked".length === applyallchecks.children('.single-role-input').length) {

            $parent.prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $parent.prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
});
```

Can you check what is wrong in my code why it is marking the "Select All"  check checked when all the single checkboxes in that container are marked as checked.

Thanks!

Comment: `applyallchecks.children('.single-role-input') + ":checked".length` seems invalid selector, can you try `applyallchecks.children('.single-role-input:checked').length`

Comment: You have two errors one is @Rayon comment and other is #checkall (you don't have any id checkall is a class)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I have updated the code, in real code i have same class on both the ends

Comment: @Rayon it seems like chidren() function was not working, I have update the condition to parent.find('.single-role-input:checked').length and it is now working fine.

Comment: *children() not working* - it's working fine, the issue is that you're trying to make a *string* selector from the result, which makes no sense.   `applyallchecks.children('.single-role-input') + ":checked".length` should have been `applyallchecks.children('.single-role-input:checked').length` - though note the difference between .children() and .find().

Comment: I got your point @freedomn-m,  not i understand the mistake in my code. anyhow it has been fixed in my answer to this question.

Comment: @shoaibMunir - I am glad problem is fixed. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the children() function so I have replace the following line of code

```
if (applyallchecks.children('.single-role-input') + ":checked".length === applyallchecks.children('.single-role-input').length)
```

With this

```
if (parent.find('.single-role-input:checked').length === parent.find('.single-role-input').length)
```

and it is now working

so the over all solution code is as following:

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkall', function() {
    var applyallchecks = $(this).parents('#role-card-single').find('.single-role-input');
    if (this.checked) {
        applyallchecks.prop('checked',true);
    } else {
        applyallchecks.prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$(document).on('change', '.single-role-input' , function(e) {
    let parent = $(this).closest('#role-card-single');
    let selectall = parent.find('.checkall');

    if($(this).is(':checked')) {

        var applyallchecks = parent.find('.custom-checkbox');
        if (parent.find('.single-role-input:checked').length === parent.find('.single-role-input').length) {
            selectall.prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            selectall.prop('checked', false);
        }
    } else {
        selectall.prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```